# Is it possible to read the body of a response in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, io

I have a `PrintWriter` from an `HttpServletResponse` and I would like to know if there is any way to read its buffer (considering the `HttpServletResponse.getWriter()` PrintWriter isn't auto-flushed).

I know there are some ways to transform an InputStream to an OutputStream through `InputStream.transferTo()` but is there any way to do it in the other way and to convert my PrintWriter to any type of OutputStream? Or is there any way just to read the response body of an `HttpServletResponse` ?

So far I've tried the `toString()` method which is not overwritten. I tried to pipe it through different streams like `PipedInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

I'm using spring boot microservices architecture btw.

Comment: Why? Forgot what you just wrote to it already? Strong smell of an XY problem here.

Comment: no i'm using a microservice architecture and I'm trying to log all request-and-response couples somplace? If that could Help you i'm using zuul-gateway as my api-gateway and I've tried with spring boot security filters and zuul filters already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to handle this through spring boot `Filter` by overriding `HttpServletResponseWrapper`.
so here's my code (the class that overrides the `HttpServletResponseWrapper` to change the response default output stream to my custom `ServletOutputStream`):

```java
public class HttpServletResponseCopier extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private ServletOutputStreamCopier copier;
    private ServletOutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    /**
     * @param response
     */
    public HttpServletResponseCopier(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException
    {
        if (outputStream != null)
            throw new IOException("output stream already called for this response");
        else {
            outputStream = getResponse().getOutputStream();
            copier = new ServletOutputStreamCopier(this.outputStream);
            return copier;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException
    {
        if (outputStream != null)
            throw new IOException("print writer already called for this response");
        else {
            outputStream = getResponse().getOutputStream();
            copier = new ServletOutputStreamCopier(outputStream);
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(copier, getResponse().getCharacterEncoding()));
            return writer;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException
    {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.flush();
        else if (copier != null)
            copier.flush();

    }

    public String getContent()
    {
        String content = "";
        try {
            content = IOUtils.toString(copier.getCopyBuffer(), getResponse().getCharacterEncoding());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }

}
```

and my ServletOutputStreamCopier class (the class that copies the content of the stream into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`):

```java
public class ServletOutputStreamCopier extends ServletOutputStream {

    private ServletOutputStream outputStream;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream copier;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public ServletOutputStreamCopier(ServletOutputStream outputStream) {
        super();
        this.outputStream = outputStream;
        this.copier = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReady()
    {
        return this.outputStream.isReady();
    }

    @Override
    public void setWriteListener(WriteListener listener)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException
    {
        if (this.copier == null)
            this.copier = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (this.outputStream == null)
            throw new IOException("outputStream is null");
        this.copier.write(b);
        this.outputStream.write(b);

    }

    public byte[] getCopyBuffer()
    {
        return this.copier.toByteArray();
    }

}
```

and finally inject it into the spring boot filter:

```java
@Component
public class LoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        HttpServletResponseCopier responseWrapper = new HttpServletResponseCopier(response);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);

        System.out.println("response body: "+responseWrapper.getContent());

    }
}
```

which outputs this:

```java
"body": <response body here>
```